# How to find subclass of superclass object? (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm writing a library management system. For the login process, I have a log (implemented via `ArrayList`) that contains objects of type, `User`. `User` is a superclass for the subtypes, `Librarian` and `Admin` (all users must be one or the other). How do I check to see if an instance of `User` is of type `Admin`? The code below is what I tried before. The issue is that I have code in the `AdminUser` constructor that I don't want executed unnecessarily. I just need to see if the passed user is of type, `Admin`.

```
public boolean isAdmin( User u )
{
    AdminUser a = new AdminUser();
    Class<? extends AdminUser> c = a.getClass();
    return u.getClass() == a.getClass();
}
```

Comment: "InstanceOf checks to see if a subclass is an instance of a superclass" isn't really correct. You can check if an instance of some superclass is an instance of one of its subclasses. In fact, that's how it's usually used. There's no point in checking if an instance of some subclass is an instance of that class's superclass. Doing `if (u instanceof Admin)` is enough

Comment: ah, thanks. looks like I misunderstood what InstanceOf does.

Comment: @hev1 yep! thanks for the help

Comment: @hev1 got it, still figuring this site out haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AdminUser.class`.

```
public boolean isAdmin(final User u)
{
    return u.getClass() == AdminUser.class;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just saying, `instanceof` works correctly.

```
public boolean isAdmin( User u )
{
    return (u instanceof Admim);
}
```

But you can use the `class` keyword.

```
public boolean isAdmin( User u )
{
    return u.class == AdminUser.class;
}
```

But I recommend using `instanceof`.